# How to get a number between underscores?

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have a key that has the following sequence of characters: `_(some number)_1`. How can I just return `(some number)`.

For example if the key is `_6654_1` I just need value `6654`. The problem/issue that's really confusing me is the number could be any length like `_9332123425234_1` in which case I would just need the `9332123425234`.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_[\\d]_1");
Matcher match = p.matcher(request.getParameter("course_id"));
```

but this won't cover the case where the middle number can be any number (not just four digits) will it?

Comment: It appears you know that regexes are one solution; so what have you tried already?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @Oli I'm a beginner and I didn't even know where to start. I guess putting regex in the tags wasn't the right tag? I was looking at Java's string class and was trying to figure out how to use the indexOf() method, but I just got confused and came here. Then I looked at the Pattern and Matcher methods and got more confused.

Comment: @Robert: What I mean is; did you look at the documentation for regexes?  Did you try anything based on what you read?

Comment: @Robert, It depends on a few things... Do you for instance know that the input follows this pattern? Or are you *searching* for tokens on this format. If you're not sure of the input format, a regular expression that describes the sought pattern may be your best option. If you're dead sure that the input will follow this pattern, I suggest you go with the indexOf or split approaches in my answer.

Comment: @aioobe I know the input will follow this pattern as it's passed in the url when the user first clicks on a link in the in app (setup by the system I'm working on).

Comment: @Oli Yes I did. I tried to pass \d into the Pattern.Compile() method, but I didn't think that would cover any number of digits.

Comment: @Robert, regarding your edit. Just replace `[\\d]` with `\\d+` :-) The `[`...`]` is redundant since `\d` is already a character class, and add a `+` in order to match more than a single digit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just figure out the `indexOf('_')` and then use `substring`. No need for regular expressions.

...but since you asked for regular expressions, here you go:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "_6654_1";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(\\d+)_1");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if (m.matches())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));  // prints 6654
    }
}
```

(And here is the `substring`-approach for comparison:)

```
String str = "_6654_1";
String num = str.substring(1, str.indexOf('_', 1));
System.out.println(num);                     // prints 6654
```

And, a final solution, using a simple `split("_")`:

```
String str = "_6654_1";
System.out.println(str.split("_")[1]);   // prints.... you guessed it: 6654
```

Comment: @aioobe Ah, so the plus sign is what makes it search for more than one digit? Thank you.

Comment: @Robert, precisely, `+` means *one or more*. FYI, `*` means zero or more. So if you want to match numbers that doesn't start with a `0` you typically use `[1-9]\d*`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need regexp? You can use `substring` and `indexOf`:

```
String st = "_9332123425234_1";
String number = st.substring(1,st.indexOf('_',1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the underscores before and after your digit sequence, you could use `_(\d+)_` to create a Capturing Group.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using a Splitter:

[Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v9.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

This might be more efficient than a regex and since it returns all the elements you will be the before and after elements as well as the number in the middle. So, if you eventually need the number after the second "_" this might be the better way to go.

Comment: never heard of Splitter, but it seems very interesting. I don't have enough rep. to give you an upvote, but I am definitely going to look at this api. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah, it is pretty slick. Check out the entire Guava API. There is a ton of really cool stuff in there. Was a real game-changer for me.